# Python selenium how to hide the browser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

I've looked and looked for something like this, but I still can't find out how to do it..

I have tried

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display.
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

but I get this error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users//PycharmProjects/untitled/PureTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\display.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._obj = self.display_class(
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyvirtualdisplay\display.py", line 51, in display_class
    cls.check_installed()
```

Comment: Have you installed `xvfb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's this for? Is this to run headless / automated tasks? If you're going to do that, I would suggest using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). It's a headless browser capable of running JavaScript that can be used with Selenium. I use PhantomJS for automation of website tasks with selenium, and no tinkering with virtual displays etc. is necessary.

If that's what you're trying to achieve I'd recommend giving PhantomJS a try!

Comment: This is for an automating web, yes, Can I send keys with this? or,

Comment: @Nevermind123 you sure can! Practically speaking you can do just about anything you would do with a "real" browser, the only difference is that it doesn't display a visual interface, so it's a lot more suitable for running automated web tasks server-side/headless.

Comment: @daveruinseverything I'm using `PhantomJS`. But when I run the script a console appears. How to stop that ?

Answer (score 0):

if "hiding web browser" you mean, that you want to print the browser title without displaying the browser using selenium, then its not possible , for that you can use phantom JS or you can also use a library in python known as Mechanize which will provide you the functionality that of a browser without showing it and using Phantom JS is also a nice idea but personally i don't prefer it as i find some issues with it.